# What is the following graph called?

Tags: graph

```
o-o-o-o-o-o-...
 x x x x x
o-o-o-o-o-o-...
```

where '-,x' are edges, and 'o' are nodes.  [i.e., two chains of nodes with crosslinks at every step]

Does it have mathematical terminology? Bonus points for whomever directs me to any theory related to Markov chains for such graphs.

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried to edit your graph to display better. Do we understand that all edges are directed, left-to-right transitions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be regular dynamic Bayesian network with two nodes, where both nodes depend on the values of both nodes at the preceding time step.  It's a coupled factorial Markov model; you can reduce it to a simple single-chain Markov model by defining the outer-product state space Q = q1 x q2, then simply tabulating all the possible transitions from $Q^{T-1}$ to $Q^T$.